# Why Superglobals can't be printed in double quotes?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$x = "world";
echo "hello $x";
echo "hello $GLOBALS['x']";
?>
```

In the above code the first statement prints hello world but second doesn't print anything.Why superglobals are not accessible in double quotes?

Comment: `echo "Hello {$GLOBALS['x']}";`or `echo "Hello $GLOBALS[x]";`

Comment: See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: you can't use quoted array keys in array vars inside double-quoted strings. welcome to PHP, where everything is ad-hoc and consistency doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that super globals can't it's that you can't access items in an array in the string. If you did the following it'll work fine.

```
echo "hello {$GLOBALS['x']}";
```